# Nested Routing and Material-UI List not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I have a problem, I am using material-ui in a sidebar but the routes are not working. This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavLink as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";

export const Sidebar = (props) => {
  const { menu } = useSelector((state) => state);
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(1);

  const handleListItemClick = (event, index) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
  };

  return (
    <List component="nav">
      {menu.map((text, index) => (
        <ListItem
          key={text.id}
          selected={selectedIndex === text.id}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, text.id)}
          component={RouterLink}
          to={text.url}
          button
        >
          .....
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
};
```

Clicking on the menu reloads the entire page.

[This is the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yehqW.png)

[SessionRouter - This is the component where I call the Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFWxX.png)

[AppRouter - This is where i call SessionRouter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W42W8.png)

[PrivateRoute component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoHCg.png)

Please help.

Comment: So the menu that your are building is working as it should, isn't it? The problem is that your screen does not change?

Comment: It does not change the component and neither does the domain, for example, at the beginning this domain.com/ruta1
I want it to go to domain.com/ruta2 but it always stays at domain.com/ruta1, try to place the Navlink wrapping the Listitem and if it changes it but reloads the whole page

Comment: in your to= {text.url} you do pass the / before the route right ?

Comment: yes, an example of the array is = [{label: "Iniciar una queja", id: 1, url:"/iniciarqueja"}]

Comment: <Route exact path="/ruta1"><ComplainScreen/> </Route> could you try this ? and place the redirect in the top of all the routes

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work, will it be a problem to use material-ui?, in other projects where I don't use material it works perfect for me.

Comment: Could you provide a codesandbox ? i could give it a try before sleep

Comment: I don't think the problem is material ui. I tried your code and it's working on my computer. I thought it too, that it might be some weir behavior between material ui and react router dom, but I don't think the problem is there

Comment: try to implement this function 
`const NavLinkMui = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <NavLink {...props} activeClassName="Mui-selected" ref={ref} />
))`

Then in the .map use this component
`<ListItem button component={NavLinkMui} to={to}>{text}</ListItem>`

I saw a github issue not long ago

Comment: Quick question. Are you setting differents components for the differents `Routes` on the `Switch`. because on the sample code, you put `ComplainScreen` for all of the routes

Comment: Another question. Are you wrapping your menu with the `Router` ??

Comment: yes, if I have different components

Comment: Did you try the code i've given u above ? it should fix it as they mention on their gitub

Comment: put more images of the code in the description so they have more context

Comment: @DarioRega , it works but reload the whole page again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now that you have added more info to your question, specifically the screenshots from `AppRouter`, `PrivateRouter` and `SessionRouter`, I was able to reproduce your problem. I will base my answer on [React Router Dom - Nesting Example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting)

As you can see, the example is somewhat the same as your code. The structure is the following:

1. A main component (in your case: `AppRouter`, in the example: `NestingExample`) with a `Router` that wraps everything, including a `Switch` with some `Route`'s.
2. A second component (in your case: `SessionRouter`, in the example: `Topics`) that has more info (in yours it's a sidebar with links and stuff) and another `Switch` with different `Route`'s from the first one.

The example from the page uses `useRouteMatch` to get the `url` and the `path` but you don't really need this since your "base route" is "/". So if you watch the hole picture you can see that your "routing" structure is exactly the same as the example from react-router-dom page. But there's a little detail and for this, I would like to invite you to try the following on the page example: in `NestingExample` function add the `exact` prop to the "topics" `Route`, like this:

```
<Switch>
     <Route exact path="/">
         <Home />
     </Route>
     <Route exact path="/topics">
         <Topics />
     </Route>
</Switch>
```

Try clicking on any of the topics and you will see that it's the same problem that you have.
So, with this, my suggestion would be to add `exact={false}` prop to the `PrivateRoute` component in `AppRouter` (since you have `...rest`)

Comment: following your first guidance it worked for me, wrapping the component 
        <PrivateRoute exact={false} path="/" isAuth={isLoggedIn}  >
          <SessionRouter />
        </PrivateRoute> , 
thank you !! this solved the reloading of the page.

Comment: Nicee to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you can pass `url` to `handleListItemClick` and when button clicked you can change page using method [push](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/28c89f4091ae9e1b0001341ea60c629674e83627/docs/api-reference.md#history.push) of [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) library:

```
const handleListItemClick = (event, index, url) => {
  setSelectedIndex(index);
  history.push(url);
};
```

And you should update rendering of `ListItem`:

```
<ListItem
  key={text.id}
  selected={selectedIndex === text.id}
  onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, text.id, text.url)}
  component={RouterLink}
  to={text.url}
  button
>
  .....
</ListItem>;
```

Comment: It works but the page is reloaded all over again ... and that is what should not happen

Comment: try to add `onClick={(event) =>e.preventDefault(); handleListItemClick(event, text.id, text.url)}`
It should stop the reload normally

Comment: @RukkiesMan , it works but keep reloading the whole page again